# Четыре раза "..ми" на конце. Что нарушаю.

Tags: стилистика, недопустимая-метка

Откроется форма с заполненными необходимыми данными полями.

Обошелся без запятых. Хотя мог бы выразиться так: "Откроется форма с полями, заполненными необходимыми данными."
Что-то меня здесь смущает, как зовётся подобная нелепица? Тавтология?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется неблагозвучие, насколько я знаю. Можно слегка разбавить эти "ми":

***Откроется форма с полями, в которые внесены  необходимые данные.***